# Multi-parameter optimization in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to estimate parameters that will maximize the likelihood of a certain event. My objective function looks like that:

```
event_prob = function(p1, p2) {
  x = ((1-p1-p2)^4)^67 *
    ((1-p1-p2)^3*p2)^5 *
    ((1-p1-p2)^3*p1)^2 *
    ((1-p1-p2)^2*p1*p2)^3 *
    ((1-p1-p2)^2*p1^2) *
    ((1-p1-p2)*p1^2*p2)^2 *
    (p1^3*p2) *
    (p1^4)
  return(x)
}
```

In this case, I'm looking for p1 and p2 [0,1] that will maximize this function. I tried using `optim()` in the following manner:

```
aaa = optim(c(0,0),event_prob)
```

but I'm getting an error "Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "p2" is missing, with no default".
Am I using `optim()` wrong? Or is there a different function (package?) I should be using for multi-parameter optimization?

Comment: optim calls your function with a single array of length 2 instead of two scalar parameters. (That makes sense: imagine you have 100 parameters).

Comment: Your likelihood looks quite amazing. How many events do you have in your outcome, 1, 2 or 3? From your definition it seems like `abs(p1 + p2) <= 1`  should be true, similar to a 3 outcome scenario. In either case `1 - p1 - p2` seems odd if that is **not** the case. If it **is** the case, then `1 - p1 - p2` is non-negative, and you should take `log` of every part of your expression and optimize over this instead. For the very first element, assume `p1=p2=0.1` then `(1 - p1 - p2)^(4 * 67)=4.742844e-188`. This is prone to errors. Also take a look at `constrOptim`, for constrained optimization.

Comment: Oh and notice `optim` and `constrOptim` performs minimization. So add a `-` to your function output. :-)

Comment: Yes, Oliver, it is a 3 outcome scenario. I actually already took ```log``` at the end (```return(log(x))```) after posting this question. Also, definitely encountered the minimization issue too, and used ```fnscale=-1``` as a control for ```optim```.
I'll have a look at ```constrOptim```. Thanks!!

Comment: Take out a piece of paper, and rewrite the result under log. Keep in mind, that all the numerical rounding errors happen while you are not on the log scale, so rewriting your likelihood **first** is almost always recommended. Good luck!

Comment: That's a very good point, thanks for that! I didn't even need a piece of paper, as in the meanwhile I've added some code to generate the probability based on my dataframe of observation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Erwin Kalvelagen's comment: Redefine your function `event_prob`:

```r
event_prob = function(p) {
  p1 = p[1]
  p2 = p[2]
  x = ((1-p1-p2)^4)^67 *
    ((1-p1-p2)^3*p2)^5 *
    ((1-p1-p2)^3*p1)^2 *
    ((1-p1-p2)^2*p1*p2)^3 *
    ((1-p1-p2)^2*p1^2) *
    ((1-p1-p2)*p1^2*p2)^2 *
    (p1^3*p2) *
    (p1^4)
  return(x)
}
```

You may want to set limits to ensure that `p1` and `p2` fulfill your constraints:

```r
optim(c(0.5,0.5),event_prob,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=0,upper=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. ```optim()``` is running now, but the results are still not right. I'm getting different results for different initial values, but I'm looking for the global maximum.

Comment: Maybe your likelihood function is not globally concave, i.e. has local maxima. In that case, optimize at different inital values to find the global maximum.

Comment: Never mind, I just needed to set ```fnscale=-1``` for it to maximize instead of minimize. It's working now!

Answer (score 1):

This problem can in fact be solved analytically.

The objective function simplifies to

```
F(p1,p2) = (1-p1-p2)^299 * p1^19 * p2^11
```

which is to be maximised over the region

```
C = { (p1,p2) | 0<=p1, 0<=p2, p1+p2<=1 }
```

Note that F is 0 if p1=0 or p2 =0 or p1+p2 = 1, while if none of those are true then F is positive. Thus the maximum of F occurs in the interior of C

Taking the log

```
f(p1,p2) = 299*log(1-p1-p2) + 19*log(p1) + 11*log(p2)
```

In fact it is as easy to solve the more general problem: maximise f over C where

```
f( p1,..pN) = b*log( 1-p1-..-pn) + Sum{ a[j]*log(p[j])}
where b and each a[j] is positive and
C = { (p1,..pN) | 0<pj, j=1..N and p1+p2+..pN<1 }
```

The critical point occurs where all the partial derivatives of f are zero, which is at

```
-b/(1-p1-..-pn) + a[j]/p[j] = 0 j=1..N
```

which can be written as

```
b*p[j] + a[j]*(p1+..p[N]) = a[j] j=1..N
```

or

```
M*p = a
where M = b*I + a*Ones', and Ones is a vector with each component 1
```

The inverse of M is

```
inv(M) = (1/b)*(I - a*Ones'/(b + Ones'*a))
```

Thus the unique critical point is

```
p^ = inv(M)*a
   = a/(b + Sum{i|a[i]})
```

Since there is a maximum, and only one critical point, the critical point must be the maximum.

Comment: Thanks for this, although I wanted to use ```optim()``` rather than solve analytically since the problem in the OP is the (much much) simpler one of 2 problems I needed to solve. Understanding how ```optim()``` and ```constrOptim()``` worked allowed me to solve the more complex one, which wouldn't fit this suggested solution, with no problem. Nonetheless, I appreciate the approach - it may come in handy in the future.